# Excel Ranking tie issue

Tags: excel, ranking, tie

Does any one know how to deal with tie records issue in Excel? I only want to show the record once on first occurrence. If same number is found twice, it will not show as I show above.

[image] [image]

Comment: So, you want to show the rank only for those rows where the ranks are repeats of those higher in the list? Or is it the case that you only want to show 1 row for each of the tied rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results shown you can use this "array formula" in AA2

`=IF(OR(Z2=0,COUNTIF(Z$2:Z2,Z2)>1),"",SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Z$2:Z$19>Z2,Z$2:Z$19),Z$2:Z$19),1))+1)`

confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copy formula down column

see [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvpoeilr9aqalt6/Ranks.xls)

Comment: Wow, what a magic formulas. I think that Microsoft should hire you for that since they don't have good rank function within excel 2010.

Comment: Hi Barry, do you know why I got #value when I copy the furmulas from your original post?

Comment: I assume you didn't use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - if formulas are changed or copied you need to apply that key combination

Comment: Hi Barry, if I want that formula to extent to entire column Z, how should I do that?

Comment: Hi Barry, based on your formula, I modified it a little bit       =IF(N(A2),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$A$1:A1,0)),"",RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$8,0)),"")

Comment: ......but in your question the four different values get ranks of 1, 2, 3 and 4 - if you use that version then the duplicates will throw that out, on your example you'll get ranks of 1, 12, 15 and 17

Comment: Hi Barry, so if using your formula how can I apply that to entire column Z?

Comment: Hi Barry, sorry I just understand what you mean by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. I never know how it works until now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would produce the result you show in the linked image would be to have two columns for rank, 1 for the raw rank results, and one for the displayed ranks.

Assuming that your data starts in cell A2, and your raw ranking results begin in cell B2, you could insert the following formula in cell C2:

```
 =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,B$1:B1,0)),B2,"")
```

Then, you would copy the formula down to the bottom row of your data.

Here's how this formula works. The MATCH function looks for the ranking shown in the current row of column B in the column B rows *above* that row. The MATCH function returns an error if there is no match, which in this case means that the current B cell has not already occurred. That's a ranking that you want to show.

If there's no error in the MATCH, there is the same ranking in the rows above - in that case, the formula returns an empty string.

Finally, you would hide column B, leaving columns A & C to be shown.

Comment: Thanks Chuff, still want to thank you even your formula not working for my excel sheet.